# Segmentation fault doesn't appear in Visual Studio but does in school server

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Good morning all,

I'm writing a simple program for school that reads lines from a .txt file and outputs the number of each character to a new file.  I've been stuck for a few hours because I can't figure out where the segmentation fault is happening. It doesn't happen when I compile and debug in visual studio, but presents itself when I compile on the school's server and run my program.  I know there are still flaws in the program beside the segmentation fault, but I'd prefer to work those out on my own :). Thanks in advance for the help.

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "letterFunctions.hpp"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::iostream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ios;

void count_letters(ifstream &ifs, int* freqArray);

int main()
{
     //Declare the string for the input file and create the input stream.
     ifstream ifs;
     string inputFileName;

     //Initialize the array for the frequency of each letter.
     int *freqArray = new int[26];

     //Prompt the user for the input file name.
     cout << "Enter the name of the file to be analyzed." << endl;
     cin >> inputFileName;

     //Open the file.
     ifs.open(inputFileName.c_str());

     //If the file doesn't exist, prompt the user for a new file.
     while (ifs.fail())
     {
          cout << "Invalid entry. Enter the name of the file to be analyzed." << endl;
          cin >> inputFileName;

          ifs.open(inputFileName.c_str());
     }


    count_letters(ifs, freqArray);

     //Close the input file.
     ifs.close();


     return 0;
}
```

letterFunctions.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "letterFunctions.hpp"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;

ofstream ofs;

void count_letters(ifstream &ifs, int* freqArray)
{
     //Initialize new variables.
     int arrayModifier = 0;
     char input;

     //Read the first character of the file.
     input = ifs.get();
     while (input != EOF)
     {
          //Reset the array to 0's.
          for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
          {
               freqArray[i] = 0;
          }

          while (input != '\n')
          {
               //Convert all chars to upper case.
               if ((int)input >= 97 && (int)input <= 122)
               {
                    putchar(toupper(input));
               }

               //Set the array modifier to the corresponding letter, and add one to the counter.
               arrayModifier = ((int)input - 65);
               freqArray[arrayModifier]++;

               //Get the next character.
               input = ifs.get();
          }

          //Output to the file.
          output_letters(ofs, freqArray);

          input = ifs.get();
     }
}

void output_letters(ofstream &ofs, int* freqArray)
{
     string outputFileName;
     cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to output this paragraph to." << endl;
     cin >> outputFileName;

     ofs.open(outputFileName.c_str());
     int l = 65;
     for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
     {
          ofs << (char)l << ": " << freqArray[i] << "\n";
          l++;
     }
     ofs.close();
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `arrayModifier = ((int)input - 65); freqArray[arrayModifier]++;` can easily cause buffer overrun

Comment: Whenever `input` character is not between `A` and `Z`, your program accesses an index out of bounds.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). For example, if you by the value `65` means the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) representation of `'A'`, then it's better to use `'A'`. On a related note, your code works only with ASCII and similar character encoding schemes, where letters are consecutive. There are encodings where that's not true (e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)).

Answer (score 0):

You have some undefined behaviour that runs fine on your pc but not on the server.

Consider what happens if I give you the following text `"this is an error!\n"` (ignore the ").